# barcode_scan Flutter plugin to only scan QR code (not to accept 2d barcode)

Tags: flutter, zxing

Scanning works fine for QR and 2d barcode. Is there other way to exclude 2d barcode for the [barcode_scan](https://pub.dev/packages/barcode_scan#-readme-tab-) Flutter plugin?

I tried the [qrcode_reader](https://pub.dev/packages/qrcode_reader) plugin but it is deprecated and there is no overlay in the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [qr_mobile_vision](https://github.com/rmtmckenzie/flutter_qr_mobile_vision).  It is insanely fast and very accurate from my usage trials.

An object defined using this library can be placed in your widget tree.

Once you master the library then based upon my understanding of what you desire. overlay, etc. I recommend you roll your own overlay using something like this pseudo code (not tested):

```
bool xHairOn=false;

Stack ( children : <Widget> [
  SizedBox (
    width: 300.0,
    height: 300.0,
    child: new QrCamera(
      qrCodeCallback: (code) {
        setState(() {
          // que changes to your overlay visuals here
          xHairOn=true;
          });

        // wait 1/2 second
        new Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
          setState(() {
              // que crosshair to disappear after 1/2 second has expired
              xHairOn=false;
              });
           });
      ),
    )
  , xHairOn == true ? Image.asset("assets/image/crosshairs.png", width: 300 , height: 300 ) 
                    : Container ( width: 300, height : 300 )
  ])
```

Note in the above I am doing this from memory, thus the Image.asset may need to be placed in the stack prior to the SizedBox Widget

Comment: Thank you for your input about the overlay. I successfully made it using qr_mobile_vision. See picture: https://ibb.co/qdpw3MB